# Sublime Text 2: Is it possible to tint sections of code?

Tags: css, text, editor

I'm new to Sublime Text 2 for Mac and I'm coding a rather sophisticated responsive style sheet with multiple breakpoints. Because a single style will appear several times (at each media query breakpoint...), I frequently 'get confused' regarding which one of several variant declarations I'm working on. It would be really awesome if I could apply a different background tint to sections of code within the same document and I can't believe I'm the only person to have thought this, but I can't seem to find a way to do it. Any suggestions?

And, yes, I could obviously break the stylesheet into multiples, corresponding to each break point, but I'd rather use a single stylesheet, if possible.

Thanks in advance.